# data-toggle: pill is not working as expected

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I am working on a Rails app with Twitter Bootstrap 2. I am trying to do something I think should be simple but I am new at using Rails with jQuery. Here's my partial: template (actually it's a partial).

```
<div class="container">
 <div class="row">
   <div class="span2">
     <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
       <li>
         <a href="#" data-toggle="pill">Trend lines for all questions</a>
       </li>
       <li>
       <%= link_to "Summary of all questions", program_reports_path(@program),
                   remote: true, id: "reports-navlist", data: {toggle: "tab"} %>
       <li class="active">
         <a href="#" data-toggle="pill">Trend lines for all questions</a>
       </li>
       <li>
         <a href="#" data-toggle="pill">Details on all questions</a>
       </li>
     </ul>
   </div>
   <div class="span10">
   </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

My problem is that I can't get the nav 'pill' activation to work right. The first, third and fourth li tags work fine (because they don't do anything.)

But the second one, the test, is throwing a JavaScript error. It does not become active and the rendering of the pill is not correct. If I remove remote:true or make it remote:false this does not fix the problem.  But if I change the url to "#" then it works. So there's an interaction there which I don't understand.

Here is the full HTML that was generated: http://pastebin.com/nKUzwvif

Here is the error that comes out of JS in Safari:

> Other Issue. Error: Syntax Error, unrecognized expression.

The code generating the error is in Sizzle:

```
Sizzle.error = function( msg ) {
    throw new Error( "Syntax error, unrecognized expression: " + msg );
};
```

Comment: Can you share the rendered html and the javascript error here.

Comment: Maybe a copy-paste error, but it looks like you're missing the closing LI tag on the second LI. You probably want `data: {toggle: 'pill'}` too.

Comment: Good catch @patrickberkeley. The missing closing LI tag helps but the js error is still coming up...

Comment: Not sure if this will help, but it's a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9780262/rails-3-2-2-with-twitter-bootstrap-tabs-ajax-not-working. Also, I don't think your error has to do with bootstrap. I think you have another js error on the page that's killing everything.

Comment: exactly the same here. Same error message. Any help please.